# some trick to have multiple styles in entry or editor in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, markdown, editor

I want a control that can be show and edit bold/cursives in the same place . I found Markdown viewers (Labels control https://github.com/dotnet-ad/MarkdownView ) but when Edit the content the entry or editor is without format and I want to see the multiples formats (bold, cursive,hyperlink..)  in Editor/Entry control NOT in label. anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: this is called WYSIWIG - see https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-rich-text-editor